# Django - display several model queries either a template or nested templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am fairly new to Django and have learned to display model data in a template (using Django.generic ListView in views) by putting everything in a table using something like:

```
{% for each in model_list %} 
<td>{{each.attribute}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

What should I do if I want to perform several queries on the same model(data) and then present each of those returned dictionaries in a different part of the template view (imagine if you had 1,000 baseball players and you wanted to display them in separate tables on the same page corrosponding to their team)?

My thought is I should use something like this from the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/

```
class PublisherBookListView(ListView):

context_object_name = "book_list"
template_name = "books/books_by_publisher.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    self.publisher = get_object_or_404(Publisher, name__iexact=self.args[0])
    return Book.objects.filter(publisher=self.publisher)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # Call the base implementation first to get a context
    context = super(PublisherBookListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # Add in the publisher
    context['publisher'] = self.publisher
    return context
```

However, using ListView it seems like you can only pass one Dictionary to the template at a time - the documentation link above shows how to do this with URL Patterns, but I was hoping to have more than one result on the same page (i.e. player stats from the Yankees and the Red Soxx together, not just a URL pattern to show the Yankees on one iteration of a template and the Red Soxx on another)

--I feel like there's a massive hole in my django understanding here... Because this seems like it should be simple: 
- maybe through parent/child templates? But then how would the URL pattern used in the 'query' work?

Another source I found was on filters - this seems fairly straightforward and somewhat promising:
http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html

Anyway, I'd appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction about what is typically done in situations like this.

Comment: You can pass as many items in the context dictionary as you like.

Comment: You can also pass a dictionary inside your context dictionary.

Comment: Thanks - in the template would I just refer to it as something like {% for each in context.some_label %} ?

Comment: No, because the context refers to everything the template can see. Just `for each in some_label`.